# UI looks good in Chrome but getting disturb in firefox

Tags: html, reactjs

[![FireFox Image[image: ][1]]][2]

[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Z2tu.png**strong text**

If you can see the width of scroll bar in google and firefox both are different.
Let me know How I can make changes in code so that  firefox will looks like goole, where width of scroll is thin.

Comment: You can set scrollbar width [official documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-width)

Comment: currently the overflow-y is set as auto

Comment: I linked to the documentation of `scrollbar-width: thin;`

Answer (score -1):

If I'm not mistaken, it depends purely on the browser used.

Comment: This is not an actual helpful answer.